# Negative binomial in GEE

Tags: r

For R packages implementing GEE such as `gee`, `geepack`, it seems that the negative binomial family is not included. I have two questions:

1. Are there any other R packages for GEE that I am not aware of?
2. If not, is there a simple step to allow the creation of a family, i.e providing the link function (`log mu`) and the variance function (`mu + mu^2/theta`), assuming `theta` is specified (otherwise the NB is not a GLM) and then to let the `gee` or `geepack` codes do the business in a similar fashion to `glm`?

Comment: A quick search, produced the following packages:  GWAF, MuMIn, multgee, repolr, CorrBin, boss, saws, ape

Comment: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-June/282116.html

Comment: `library("sos"); findFn("{generalized estimating equation}")` is useful -- finds a similar list to @RicardoSaporta's above -- but note that not all of these actually fit GEEs, some just leverage `geepack` or others as part of other procedures

Comment: @BenBolker: Thank you Prof. Bolker for pointing out the convenient `findFn` of finding relevant packages/functions -- Very useful!

Answer (score 8):

You should be able to use the `negative.binomial` family defined in the `MASS` package to do this (set up a NB family with a specified theta value). It looks like `geepack::geese` (at least) will accept family specifications in this form.  To estimate theta you might try embedding the GEE fit with a fixed theta into a loop, or make a `geefit_NB(theta)` function and optimize over `theta`.

If `negative.binomial` did not already exist in `MASS`, you could define your own family (this is admittedly a bit advanced -- I would start by downloading the source code of the `MASS` package and looking at the file `R/neg.bin.R`).

Comment: Thanks! I plan to add a `negbin` option in the `geese.fit` function via `VARIANCE`, which only contains gaussian, binomial, poisson and Gamma for now. I guess the key part is to find an effective way to let `geese.fit` take the results from a negative binomial fit from the MASS package. This, as you said, might be a bit advanced and I haven't find any sources for a toy example...

Comment: You're right that it's harder than I thought -- I thought that the existence of `family` meant that it could automatically use a user-defined (or at least non-package-defined) variance, but I see that the variance types are hard-coded in calls to C code ...

Comment: In retrospect, I don't think this answer actually answers the question, because (as stated in the comment above) the variance function is more hard-coded than I thought.  Worse, I don't see an obvious place in either `gee` or `geepack` to pass a parameter in to the variance function (the only adjustable parameter with respect to the variance is the scale parameter, which is an overall proportionality constant ...)

Comment: thanks for the inputs -- yes, I also realize that extra works are needed... Happy new year!