# How do I designate a negative binomial error distribution in a GLM using R?

Tags: r, glm

I'm constructing a model using the `glm()` function in R. Let's say that I know that my data have an error distribution that fits a negative binomial distribution.

When I search the R manual for the various families, `family=binomial` is offered as an option, but `negative binomial` is not.

In the same section of the R manual (family), `NegBinomial` is linked in the "See also" section, but it is presented in the context of binomial coefficients (and I'm not even sure what this is referring to).

So, to summarize, I'm hoping to find syntax that would be analogous to `glm(y~x, family=negbinomial, data=d,na.omit)`.

Comment: Please see `dnbinom(x, size, prob, mu, log = FALSE)` for negative binomial.

Comment: @Metrics thanks. But how would I designate this as the family for a glm?

Comment: I am not sure if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13946540/negative-binomial-in-gee) helps you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With an unknown overdispersion parameter, the negative binomial is not part of the negative exponential family, so can't be fitted as a standard GLM (or by `glm()`).  There is a `glm.nb()` function in the `MASS` package that can help you ...

```
library(MASS)
glm.nb(y~x, ...)
```

If you happen to have a known/fixed overdispersion parameter (e.g. if you want to fit a geometric distribution model, which has `theta=1`), you can use the `negative.binomial` family from `MASS`:

```
glm(y~x,family=negative.binomial(theta=1), ...)
```

It might not hurt if `MASS::glm.nb` were in the "See Also" section of `?glm` ...

Comment: for your second section of code, do you mean, `glm.nb(y~x, family=negative.binomial`...?

Comment: no, I don't. `glm.nb` is a specialized version of `glm` that assumes negative binomial (and estimates the theta parameter); `negative.binomial()` is a standard family that can be passed to `glm()`.

Comment: Are the overdispersion parameter and theta synonymous?

Comment: Yes.  (Although more generally you have to be careful because some people refer to theta as the overdispersion parameter, but others use 1/theta)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe theta is the overdispersion parameter. Theta is a shape parameter for the distribution and overdispersion is the same as k, as discussed in The R Book (Crawley 2007). The model output from a glm.nb() model implies that theta does not equal the overdispersion parameter:

Dispersion parameter for Negative Binomial(0.493) family taken to be 0.4623841

The dispersion parameter is a different value than theta.

Comment: this is interesting.  Can you give a reproducible example that gives the output you show above?  When I do `set.seed(101); d <- data.frame(y=rnbinom(1000,size=0.5,mu=2),x=runif(1000)); m <- glm.nb(y~x,data=d); summary(m)` I get summary output of the form `(Dispersion parameter for Negative Binomial(0.4884) family taken to be 1)`.  This is partly a matter of semantics, I think: in the strict sense of GLMs, here the dispersion parameter (phi) is being fixed to 1, but people often refer to the theta parameter of the NB as an "overdispersion parameter" ...