# Any updates to model negative binomial distribution data with GEE in R?

Tags: r

Goal: run GEE with negative binomial distribution to analyze dataset in R

This question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13946540/negative-binomial-in-gee), but the answers are ~5 years old and I wonder if there are new developments. I summarize my data and then outline how I've tried to find a solution.

My model (successfully runs using a Poisson rather than negative binomial distribution with package geeglm):

```
m1 <- geeglm(Diract ~ Dir*Rec + Year + offset(LnScan), 
             family = poisson("log"), data = Direct, id = ID, corstr = "exchangeable")
```

Data are [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YU46IMonX_AoUFT7n5vt2PKJjb3xX378/view?usp=sharing)

**Diract**: interval outcome variable, counts of behaviors from directors (“Dir” in group B or C) to recipients (“Rec" of groups A, B, or C). Range from 0-4, overdispersed.
**Dir*Rec**: main predictor of interest, interaction of two factors (director and recipient group). Animals belong to one of 3 groups (life stages): A, B, C.
**Year**: year of data collection (2010, 2011, 2012)
Goal family: negative binomial with log link function

Some individuals (~5) transitioned from one group to another between periods of data collection during the three years of study. I have multiple measures for each director (both within and between years). E.g., an individual who was alive for the entire study has counts of the behavior directed toward groups A, B, and C for each of the three years of study (total = 9 counts). Some individuals were observed all three years, others were only observed one or two years.

Initially I used GEE in SPSS, software I longer have access to. In SPSS, QIC values indicated that negative binomial was a dramatically better fit for my data vs. Poisson.

**Solution1** suggested via Stackoverflow link above: use `library("sos")` and `findFn("{generalized estimating equation}")` to find packages in R that run GEEs. I checked all 14 packages suggested. `geepack` lacks negative binomial family; `Zelig`, `JGEE`, `pseudo`, `aftgee`, `etm`, `wgeesel`, `MethylCapSig`, and `miLineage` leverage `geepack`. `MESS`, `PGEE`, `spind`, and `threeboost` lack negative binomial, and `repolr` is solely for ordinal outcomes.

**Solution2** suggested by Ben Bolker on [Nabble](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Negative-Binomial-Regression-td861977.html): "I would try glmmPQL in the MASS package.  I don't think you can *quite* get negative binomial regression this way, but you can definitely get a quasipoisson model. I think exchangeable
correlation corresponds to correlation=corCompSymm() in your glmmPQL command."

My attempt with error message:

```
m2 <- glmmPQL(Diract ~ Dir*Rec + offset(LnScan) + Year, 
              random = ~ 1 | ID, 
              family = negative.binomial(1), 
              data = Direct, 
              correlation = corCompSymm(form=~1|ID))
```

> Error in glmmPQL(Diract ~ DirPar * RecPar + offset(LnScan) + Year, random = ~1 |  : could not find function "corCompSymm"

Answer (score 4):

This question has been asked a number of times over the years and I came across it after encountering the same problem and searching for an answer for a couple of hours.  Two solutions:

1. The `geeM` package allows use of the negative binomial family
2. via the R `reticulate` package import the python `statsmodels` module and call the gee          fitting function within R which allows the negative binomial family